# Elasticsearch filter document ids with same field values count

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to return ids of documents that have the same myField value repeated [range] times. 
i.e. I have clientName field and want to find ids of all documents where clientName = 'John' but only if this name is found in 2-3 documents.

I have the following query

```
_search?filter_path=hits.total,hits.hits._id


"query": {
    some filters that return matching document ids
 },
"post_filter": {
    "bool": {
        "should": [
            {
                "range": {
                    "myField": {
                        "lte": 3,
                        "gte": 2
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
}
```

but it returns the range of myField values and not myField values count.
I tried using aggregations but aggregation filters do not apply to the main query results. 
How do I modify my post_filter to get the results I require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Post_filter:**

> The post_filter is applied to the search hits at the very end of a search request, after aggregations have already been calculated

You cannot filter documents based on number of occurrence of a field in query or post_filter and neither can you use an aggregation result to filter documents in query.

Solution to the problem can be achieved in two ways

**1. Get the terms which occur given number of times and search the documents for these terms (2 calls to the elastic search)**

**2. Get documents in aggregation itself using [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)**

Mapping:

```
{
  "index48" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "name" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "NAME": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "name.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "documents": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        },
        "bucket_count": {
        "bucket_selector": {
          "buckets_path": {
            "path": "_count"
          },
          "script": "if(params.path>=1 && params.path<=3) return true"
        }
      }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "NAME" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "John",
          "doc_count" : 3,
          "documents" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 3,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index48",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "ZRPC3HABF9RqmGpImxj_",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "name" : "John"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "index48",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "ZhPC3HABF9RqmGpIpBh4",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "name" : "John"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "index48",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "ZxPC3HABF9RqmGpIqRhj",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "name" : "John"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Doe",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "documents" : {
            "hits" : {
              "total" : {
                "value" : 2,
                "relation" : "eq"
              },
              "max_score" : 1.0,
              "hits" : [
                {
                  "_index" : "index48",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "aBPC3HABF9RqmGpIyhhU",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "name" : "Doe"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index" : "index48",
                  "_type" : "_doc",
                  "_id" : "aRPC3HABF9RqmGpIzhh7",
                  "_score" : 1.0,
                  "_source" : {
                    "name" : "Doe"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```